# Detect if two audio files are generated by the same instrument

Tags: classification, audio-processing, audio-analysis

What I'm trying to do is to detect in a small set of audio samples if any are generated by the same instrument. If so, those are considered duplicates and filtered out.

Listen to [this file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rh9vg1rpvxr07q9/samples.mp3?dl=0) of ten concatenated samples. You can hear that the first five are all generated by the same instrument (an electric piano) so four of them are to be deemed duplicates.

What algorithm or method can I use to solve this problem? Note that I don't need full-fledged instrument detection as I'm only interested in whether the instrument is or isn't the same. Note also that I don't mean literally "the same instrument" but rather "the same acoustic flavor just different pitches."

Comment: Are all your input files playing the same notes?

Comment: Do you have access to, or can you create, a large labeled dataset. Typ at least 100 examples for each instrument, for all of the relevant instruments.

Comment: Listen to the audio file. The first five samples are piano chords and the remaining are of percussive and other instruments. I don't have a dataset, but if there is an existing dataset on which a model has been trained I could use that.

Comment: Those are different notes within and across instruments. It is quite challenging for a model to distinguish *only* timbre of an instrument, and removing the influence of different notes. Just detecting notes (Fundamental frequency, F0 estimation) is considered challenging.

Comment: The most relevant dataset is probably https://magenta.tensorflow.org/datasets/nsynth

Comment: Relevant paper: MUSIC INSTRUMENT DETECTION USING LSTMS AND THE NSYNTH DATASET
https://ccrma.stanford.edu/groups/meri/assets/pdf/frisbie2017ISMIR_LBD.pdf

Comment: Provided a more comprehensive answer now

Answer (score 0):

#### Task Formulation

What you need is a Similarity Metric (a type of Distance Metric), that predicts two samples of the same instrument / instrument type as very similar (low score) and two samples of different instruments as quite different (high score). And that this holds regardless of which note is being played. So it should be sensitive to [timbre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timbre), and not sensitive to musical content.

#### Learning setup

The task can be referred to as [Similarity Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_learning). A popular and effective approach for neural networks is [Triplet Loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplet_loss). Here is a [blog-post](https://towardsdatascience.com/image-similarity-using-triplet-loss-3744c0f67973) introducing the concept in the context of image similarity. It has been applied successfully to audio before.

#### Model architecture

The primary model architecture I would consider would be a Convolutional Neural Network on log-mel spectrograms. Try first to use a generic model like [OpenL3](https://github.com/marl/openl3) as a feature extractor. It produces a 1024 dimensional output called an Audio Embedding, which you can do a triplet loss model on top of.

#### Datasets

The key to success for your application will to have a suitable dataset. You might be able to utilize the [Nsynth dataset](https://magenta.tensorflow.org/datasets/nsynth). Maybe training on that alone can give OK performance. Or you may be able to use it as a training set, and then fine-tune on your own training set.

You will at a minimum need to create a validation/test set for your own audio clips, in order to evaluate performance of the model. Minimum some 10-100 labeled examples of each instrument type of interest.